# How do I let the user of my plugin customize a custom highlight group I define?

Tags: highlight, plugin-system, highlighting

In [this plugin for (soft-)wrapping only the current line](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap), I have defined a highlight group, [`au ColorScheme * hi SoftWrapHighlightGroup ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE`](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap/blob/7fb148e19f884594767d94d9c8109ec76b2a08ba/plugin/softwrap.vim#L9), which I use [here](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap/blob/7fb148e19f884594767d94d9c8109ec76b2a08ba/plugin/softwrap.vim#L50) as an argument to [a call to `popup_create`](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap/blob/7fb148e19f884594767d94d9c8109ec76b2a08ba/plugin/softwrap.vim#L44).

How can I let the user alter `SoftWrapHighlightGroup`? Also, where should they set it?

I thought [`default`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahi-default) was the key, but I've not really understood how to use it.

As regards *where* the user of the plugin would make the change, I think it should be in the vimrc, because it's not a *filetype-specific* syntax highlighting. It's not a *syntax* highlighting at all. In this regards, I'm now thinking I should probably have the `:highlight` command above *not* in the `:autocmd` at all.

---

Indeed, with

```
hi default SoftWrapHighlightGroup ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE cterm=bold
```

in my plugin, I do see the effect of `cterm=bold`, but I'm sure I've read in several places that I should put `highlight` commands in an `autocmd`. Does it apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The recommendation to use the `ColorScheme` autocommand comes from the fact that color schemes all start with `hi clear`, which effectively removes *any* previous `hi` definition, wherever, whenever, and whoever made them. No `hi` survives `hi clear` so, if one wants their custom `hi` to stick around, then forcing their re-definition after any potential `hi clear` is the only way.

   Before dealing with your user-related problem, there is another one to deal with: your `hi` command is made inside a plugin and plugins are sourced after the user's `vimrc`, where most `colorscheme foobar` commands are. Since you are using the `ColorScheme` autocommand to define your highlight group, it will only be defined *after* the next `colorscheme foobar`… which may never happen.

   Therefore, you should have something like the following in your plugin:

   ```
   highlight SoftWrapHighlightGroup ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE
   autocmd ColorScheme * highlight SoftWrapHighlightGroup ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE
   ```

   1. a simple `hi` that will take effect right here and right now, no matter what,
   2. an autocommamd that makes sure your `hi` survives any future `hi clear`.
2. Now, how to let the user customize that highlight group when it is defined so aggressively?

   My advice would be to tell your users to add a line like the following to their `vimrc` *before* any `colorscheme` command:

   ```
   autocmd ColorScheme * highlight SoftWrapHighlightGroup ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE
   ```

   and, in your plugin, to check if they did so via `:help hlget()` before deciding to define the highlight group or not:

   ```
   if hlget('SoftWrapHighlightGroup')->empty()
       highlight SoftWrapHighlightGroup ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE
       autocmd ColorScheme * highlight SoftWrapHighlightGroup ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE
   endif
   ```

Comment: Since I have to support Vim < 8.2.3917, I can't use `hlget` there. [For now I'm branching on the version and using `try`/`catch`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39749/how-can-i-check-whether-the-user-has-defined-a-highlight-group-before-vim-8-2-39/39750#39750); I wonder if that's the best solution.

Comment: Why not using `default` instead of manually checking wihth the `if`?

Comment: No reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

1. Setting colors to NONE is (almost) the same as inheriting from Normal group. So you can simply test `hlID()` return value before calling `popup_create()` and pass "Normal" if the custom group doesn't exist (yet). Actually, popup_create will never complain, so you can even skip the test completely and pass custom group name no matter what. Then by default the colors will be "Normal" anyway.
2. In general case, it makes sense to ensure group creation by doing `hi def link custom_group NONE`. This will have no effect if the group already exists.
3. `hi def link` survives any `hi clear`, so you can default-link your group to any of standard groups (ones that are always set up by any color scheme) to get some highlighting other than Normal. While still permitting any sort of customization. This is how most of syntax plugins work. The actual colors will also depend on current color scheme, of course, but this is usually okay.
4. If you really want to set some fixed colors for all color schemes at once, then use `hi default`. First time on startup, then after every color scheme change by `ColorScheme` auto-command. What hi-default does, it sets group colors only if the group is cleared, otherwise it has no effect.
5. If user wants to customize your group he has to make use of either hi-def-link, or `ColorScheme` auto-command. There's no "third way" unless you're going to implement some sort of dedicated API that will simplify (from user pov) messing with `ColorScheme` event specifically.